# Bluetooth module(HC 05) issues

Tags: serial, programming, bluetooth

I am trying to make a Bluetooth controlled 4WD robot. i was following a tutorial i found online (https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-robot-car-wireless-control-using-hc-05-bluetooth-nrf24l01-and-hc-12-transceiver-modules/). After successfully connecting my 2 HC 05 Bluetooth module i used the script from the tutorial and modified it slightly so it would work for my set up.
The code for the robot:

```
//Code for Slave
#define enA 9
#define in1 8
#define in2 7
#define enB 10
#define in3 6
#define in4 5
int xAxis, yAxis;
unsigned int  x = 0;
unsigned int  y = 0;
int motorSpeedA = 0;
int motorSpeedB = 0;
void setup() {
  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600); // Default communication rate of the Bluetooth module
}
void loop() {
  // Default value - no movement when the Joystick stays in the center
  x = 510 / 4;
  y = 510 / 4;
  // Read the incoming data from the Joystick, or the master Bluetooth device
  while (Serial.available() >= 2) {
    x = Serial.read();
    Serial.print("X: ");
    Serial.println(x);
    delay(10);
    y = Serial.read();
    Serial.print("Y: ");
    Serial.println(y);
  }
  delay(10);
  // Convert back the 0 - 255 range to 0 - 1023, suitable for motor control code below
  xAxis = x*4;
  yAxis = y*4;
  // Y-axis used for forward and backward control
  if (yAxis < 470) {
    backMov;
    // Convert the declining Y-axis readings for going backward from 470 to 0 into 0 to 255 value for the PWM signal for increasing the motor speed
    motorSpeedA = map(yAxis, 470, 0, 0, 255);
    motorSpeedB = map(yAxis, 470, 0, 0, 255);
  }
  else if (yAxis > 550) {
    fowardMov;
    // Convert the increasing Y-axis readings for going forward from 550 to 1023 into 0 to 255 value for the PWM signal for increasing the motor speed
    motorSpeedA = map(yAxis, 550, 1023, 0, 255);
    motorSpeedB = map(yAxis, 550, 1023, 0, 255);
  }
  // If joystick stays in middle the motors are not moving
  else {
    motorSpeedA = 0;
    motorSpeedB = 0;
  }
  // X-axis used for left and right control
  if (xAxis < 470) {
    // Convert the declining X-axis readings from 470 to 0 into increasing 0 to 255 value
    int xMapped = map(xAxis, 470, 0, 0, 255);
    // Move to left - decrease left motor speed, increase right motor speed
    motorSpeedA = motorSpeedA + xMapped;
    motorSpeedB = motorSpeedB - xMapped;
    // Confine the range from 0 to 255
    if (motorSpeedA > 255) {
      motorSpeedA = 255;
    }
    if (motorSpeedB < 0) {
      motorSpeedB = 0;
    }
  }
  if (xAxis > 550) {
    // Convert the increasing X-axis readings from 550 to 1023 into 0 to 255 value
    int xMapped = map(xAxis, 550, 1023, 0, 255);
    // Move right - decrease right motor speed, increase left motor speed
    motorSpeedA = motorSpeedA - xMapped;
    motorSpeedB = motorSpeedB + xMapped;
    // Confine the range from 0 to 255
    if (motorSpeedA < 0) {
      motorSpeedA = 0;
    }
    if (motorSpeedB > 255) {
      motorSpeedB = 255;
    }
  }
  // Prevent buzzing at low speeds (Adjust according to your motors. My motors couldn't start moving if PWM value was below value of 70)
  if (motorSpeedA < 70) {
    motorSpeedA = 0;
  }
  if (motorSpeedB < 70) {
    motorSpeedB = 0;
  }
  analogWrite(enA, motorSpeedA); // Send PWM signal to motor A
  analogWrite(enB, motorSpeedB); // Send PWM signal to motor B
}
void fowardMov(){
  digitalWrite(in2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in4,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
}

void backMov(){
  digitalWrite(in1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in3,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
}
```

The code for the Controller:

```
#define Xaxis A0
#define Yaxis A1

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 Serial.write(analogRead(Xaxis)/4);
 Serial.write(analogRead(Yaxis)/4);
 delay(20);
}
```

After uploading the code i tried to move it but it wasn't working so i put print statements to see the value of X and Y. initially it didn't work so i swapped the Bluetooth modules i had and reconnected them. i also changed this line.

```
 while (Serial.available() >= 2)
```

To this

```
 if (Serial.available() > 0)
```

i started to receive values from the master to the slave but  i noticed the values were the same for x and y so i searched for another tutorial on the internet and found this (https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/andriy-baranov/arduino-4wd-rc-car-639953?ref=similar&ref_id=18369&offset=3) reading his code i wondered how did the slave work. According to the official Arduino documentation Serial.read() does not take in any arguments but i still tried it and it didn't work. I decided to retry the code from the first tutorial i checked this time it looked like it was working so i tried moving the joystick and the serial monitor printed correct values for both at first then it swaps their values then freezes. How can i stop it from freezing and swapping the values? Also why doesn't the while loop run forever isn't the amount of data in the serial buffer always higher than 2? Thank you.[image: diagram of slave]

[image: diagram of master]

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the way in which the data is sent and received because it assumes the transmission will remain perfectly synchronised for the lifetime of the programme. Consider what would happen if one byte were to be dropped due to a communication error – the x and y data would be swapped for further transmissions.

**Original Sender**

```cpp
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 Serial.write(analogRead(Xaxis)/4);
 Serial.write(analogRead(Yaxis)/4);
 delay(20);
}
```

**Original Receiver**

```cpp
void loop() {
  // Default value - no movement when the Joystick stays in the center
  x = 510 / 4;
  y = 510 / 4;
  // Read the incoming data from the Joystick, or the master Bluetooth device
  while (Serial.available() >= 2) {
    x = Serial.read();
    Serial.print("X: ");
    Serial.println(x);
    delay(10);
    y = Serial.read();
    Serial.print("Y: ");
    Serial.println(y);
  }
  delay(10);
  . . .
}
```

Therefore, there needs to be a way to synchronise to the first byte of the message. This can be achieved by using message packets where the start and end of the message are delimited with unique characters, e.g. `{` and `}`, similar to the [JSON format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

As another example, the [NMEA GPS](https://www.gpsworld.com/what-exactly-is-gps-nmea-data/) standard uses `$` and `\n` to delimit messages, and `,` to delimit fields. It also has a checksum at the end.

Here is a non-blocking algorithm which builds upon [Majenko's `readline()` example](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino) and the [Blink Without Delay example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/BlinkWithoutDelay/) to read a packet. `ReadPacket()` returns true when incoming data has been accumulated into a valid packet. The LED is flashed to indicate that the MCU hasn't frozen.

**New Sender**

```cpp
void loop()
{
    Serial.print("{");                  // First character delimiter.
    Serial.print(analogRead(Xaxis));    // Full resolution. No need to divide by 4.
    Serial.print(",");                  // Field delimiter.
    Serial.print(analogRead(Yaxis));    // Full resolution. No need to divide by 4.
    Serial.print("}");                  // Last character delimiter.
    delay(20);
}
```

**New Receiver**

```cpp
void loop()
{
    //
    // TASK 1: Blink without delay to indicate that MCU hasn't frozen.
    //
    const unsigned int INTERVAL = 250;
    unsigned long current_timestamp = millis();
    static unsigned long previous_timestamp = current_timestamp;
    static bool led_state = false;
    if (current_timestamp - previous_timestamp >= INTERVAL)
    {
        led_state = !led_state;
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, led_state);
        previous_timestamp += INTERVAL;
    }

    //
    // TASK 2: Read and parse data packet.
    //
    static char packet[100];
    const byte NUM_FIELDS = 2;
    unsigned int fields[NUM_FIELDS];
    static unsigned int x = 512;   // Full resolution. No need to divide by 4.
    static unsigned int y = 512;   // Full resolution. No need to divide by 4.
    bool new_x = false;
    bool new_y = false;
    if (ReadPacket(Serial, packet, sizeof(packet)))
    {
        Serial.print(F("Received packet >"));
        Serial.print(packet);
        Serial.println(F("<"));

        // Parse the packet for x and y values at full resolution.
        const char delimiters[] = "{,}";
        char* field;
        int i = 0;
        field = strtok(packet, delimiters);
        while (field != NULL && i < NUM_FIELDS)
        {
            Serial.print("field = ");
            Serial.println(field);
            fields[i] = atoi(field);
            Serial.print("fields[");
            Serial.print(i);
            Serial.print("] = ");
            Serial.println(fields[i]);
            field = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
            i++;
        }
        if (i == NUM_FIELDS)
        {
            if (x != fields[0])
            {
                new_x = true;
                x = fields[0];  // Full resolution. No need to multiply by 4.
                Serial.print("New x = ");
                Serial.println(x);
            }
            if (y != fields[1])
            {
                new_y = true;
                y = fields[1];  // Full resolution. No need to multiply by 4.
                Serial.print("New y = ");
                Serial.println(y);
            }
        }
    }

    Serial.print("x = ");
    Serial.println(x);
    Serial.print("y = ");
    Serial.println(y);

    //
    // TASK 3: Process x and y values.
    //
    if (new_x || new_y)
    {
        Serial.println("Processing new values.");
        
        . . .
    }
}

bool ReadPacket(Stream& stream, char *const packet, const unsigned int SIZE)
{
    const char FIRST = '{';
    const char LAST = '}';
    static bool read_until_last = false;
    static unsigned int i = 0;
    char ch;

    if (stream.available())
    {
        ch = stream.read();

        if (ch == FIRST)
        {
            Serial.println(F("Received FIRST."));
            i = 0;
            packet[0] = ch;
            read_until_last = true;
            return false;
        }
        if (read_until_last)
        {
            i++;
            if (i > SIZE - 2)
            {
                Serial.println(F("Buffer overrun. Resetting to look for next packet."));
                i = 0;
                read_until_last = false;
                return false;
            }
            if (ch == LAST)
            {
                Serial.println(F("Received LAST."));
                packet[i++] = ch;
                packet[i] = 0;
                read_until_last = false;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Serial.print(F("Received char >"));
                Serial.print(ch);
                Serial.println("<");
                packet[i] = ch;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is WAY too complex!  Simplify your setup to the point where it only deals with just the piece that is giving you problems; in your case serial port comms between master and slave.  Solve JUST THAT problem, and then move on

Comment: I have simplified my setup by removing everything  except the master and slave Bluetooth devices . i made a simple sketch to send data from the master to the slave. it still does the  same thing. it freezes then after a while it prints out all the data sent by the master device. i noticed when i increase the delay for the master to 1 second it works a lot better but won't a delay of 1 second cause a noticeable time lag when controlling the robot? Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear you simplified things, and are starting to get some encouraging results.  If increasing the Master's delay to 1sec works a lot better, then you may be on to something.  Try increasing the delay even further (2sec, 10 sec) and see if that allows the master/slave response to look more like 'real time'.  If so, you may find that the master/slave serial rate is too low, and the 1 second delay is required to get all the bytes through the channel

Comment: In any case, take your time, go very slowly, write everything down, and ONLY CHANGE ONE THING AT A TIME.  At some point you will look at your results and your notes and say "Of course, why didn't I think of that earlier" ;-).

Comment: I did what you said and noticed something. i started the masters delay from 2 secs and started gradually decreasing it by half. At 125 millisecond it was still receiving serial data normally but with a little noticeable lag sometimes. the lag doesn't last up to a second though. I'm going to modify the code for the robot slightly so it doesn't need to send as much data. in the first tutorial the baud rate he uses is 38400 but i use 9600 do you think that could be the solution to my problem? thank you

Comment: The old 9600 baud rate is ancient. Try 115200 or 230400

Comment: I tried changing the baud rate.but it didn't improve things

Comment: If you have a 'freeze' that isn't affected by baud rate, then maybe your code sets up and then dismantles the connection each time through the loop, instead of setting it up once and then keeping it open throughout the life of the program.  There HAS to be a reason, and careful experimentation and result recording WILL reveal it.

Comment: Do you think the problem i have is with hardware? because i made my code as easy as possible by sending numbers 1-255 from the master with a for loop and then receiving and printing out the received data in the Serial monitor yet it still freezes. using a baud rate of 23400 i only got what looked like random numbers. i noticed that if remove the delay entirely from the master it doesn't freeze although some data is lost.

Comment: in general, hardware is almost never the problem